# Get SCNMaterial's frame

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, frame

I have an iPhone 3D model in my SceneKit application, it has a material which I get. It is called `iScreen` (the image that "is on" the screen of the iPhone):

```
var iScreen: SCNMaterial!
iScreen = iphone.geometry?.materialWithName("Screen")!
```

I decided to somehow project a webView there instead of an image. 
Therefore I need the frame / position / size of the screen where `iScreen` "draws" to set the UIWebView's frame. Is that possible?

**Note**

Of course I tried position, frame, size, etc. but that all was not available :/

Answer (score 0):

you will first have to know to which `SCNGeometryElement` the material applies (an `SCNGeometry` is made of one or several `SCNGeometryElement`).

That geometry element is essentially a list of indices to retrieve vertex data contained in the geometry's `SCNGeometrySources`. Here you are interested in the *position* source (it gives you the 3D coordinates of the vertices).

By iterating over these positions you'll be able to find the element's width and height.

Comment: How do I get that `SCNGeometryElement`?

Comment: if the material you're interested in is the *i*-th material in the geometry's `materials` array, then it is `-[geometry geometryElementAtIndex:i]`